# How to make custom border for a Form without Title Bar?

Tags: c#, forms, border

I have a form without Title bar, but I want my Form still have border, like this:

[image]

Currently, I used a textbox then send it to back, my Form have 1px-border. I build tiny app, so I dont want write long code to draw border. Is there any simple way to do this: **I want my Form have simple black-3px-border, but without Title Bar???**

Language: C#

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have removed title bar by setting ControlBox to false and FormBorderStyle to None

Then you can subscribe for Form.Paint event and use similar handler:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 3),
                            this.DisplayRectangle);                                     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `Form.Paint` event or override the `OnPaint` method.  There's lots of examples around the web, like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17874/Custom-shaped-form-with-a-drop-down-in-C for example.